# how do i sendkeys DOWN ARROW?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

in vb.net i want to do a sendkeys for the down arrow. what is the code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
' make sure you have this at the top:
Imports System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys


' and then you can use this:
SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}")
```

Go here for more examples and detailed information about SendKeys in VB.Net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 5):

While I won't question why, you can see [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) says you send "{DOWN}"

Specifically:

```
SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}")
```